# How to get browser and browser version used by a WebView using Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to get the browser (e.g. Safari) and the browser version of the browser that is used in a WKWebView when it opens up an URL. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`WKWebView` doesn't "use a browser". `WKWebView` is the browser engine that is used by Safari. As a matter of fact, all web browsers on iOS are explicitly required to use `WebKit` framework, as per [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> 2.5.6 Apps that browse the web must use the appropriate WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a webView in the iOS app. Users can input an URL and the webView will open it. Do you mean that it does not use a browser to open the URL and therefore there is no such thing as browser and browser version in a webView inside an iOS app?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that.